# Can't use AutoHotKey in installer to uninstall program

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make AutoHotkey script to uninstall some desktop application, but when installer application opens, script doesn't see this window. This problem reproduces with uninstallation of [7-Zip](https://7-zip.org). First of all, I disabled UAC in my Windows 10, so it will not disturb the script. Then I run the script:

```
Numpad0 & Numpad9::
Run, appwiz.cpl
Sleep, 1000
Send {TAB 4} ; Switch to text field
Sleep, 50
Send 7-Zip ; Find the product
Sleep, 1500
Send {Tab 6} ; Switch to product string
Sleep, 100
Send {Space} ; Activate product string
Sleep, 100
Send {Enter} ; Press product string
Sleep, 1000
Send U; Press Uninstall button
return
```

In this script everything works except last keypress. I tried to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>U</kbd>, I checked the current keyboard layout, nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FAQ of AHK, the problem was solved by running the script as administrator. Now it works.